# Kill Redis Slave if master is down for a given time

Tags: redis

I want to kill slave if master is down for time exceeding some threshold.

The info command on slave prints master_link_down_since_seconds. This can be used by an external process to kill the master.

I want to know if redis provides a solution for this out of the box. Is there some config in redis.conf like kill_slave_if_master_down_for which can be used to kill slave automatically ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no such system. Redis' typical answer to this is to use [Redis Sentinel](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel) to elect one of the surviving slaves as a new master and recoordinate any other nodes around it.

You could certainly write a process to just kill orphaned nodes, though.